# How can I select rows only where first digit is a number from 0 to 9?

Tags: php, mysql

As far as I know I can do something like:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE my_field LIKE '0%' 
 OR my_field LIKE '1%' 
 OR my_field LIKE '2%' ";
```

Is there a way to achieve this with a regular expression or something like this:

```
"SELECT * 
 FROM my_table 
 WHERE my_field LIKE [only first char is 0-9]"??
```

**EDIT: The field is not numeric and it can be something like "1 People", "211 Pies" and so on.**

Comment: MySQL supports the `RLIKE` option http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM BadlyDesignedTable 
WHERE AnswerColumn RLIKE '^[0-9]+'
```

I was wondering if it was even possible to regex in where, found it on google in 30 seconds.

Comment: You don't really need the `+`, but it won't hurt anything

Comment: Is it better to use RLIKE instead of REGEXP like mavili explains?

Comment: @Uuid: `RLIKE` is an alias of `REGEXP`. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html

Comment: From MySQL manual: "RLIKE is a synonym for REGEXP, provided for mSQL compatibility."

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE field REGEXP '^[0-9]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * From my_table Where (REGEXP_LIKE(my_field, '[[:digit:]]%'))
```

The `(REGEXP_LIKE(Source_String, '[[:character class:]]'))` is a function you can use for numerous issues such as the one you have. Simply use it to tell it to do that for the first digit.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

EDIT: Select * From my_table Where (SUBSTR(my_field,1,1) = '[[:digit:]]')
Tried this in a similar query of mine, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE left(my_field,1) REGEXP '^[0-9]+';
```

If you have MSSQL you can use

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE isNumeric(left(my_field,1)) = 1
```

Comment: don't know which DB you're on, but isnumeric is NOT a mysql function.

Comment: Wouldn't this return values between 10 and 19? and including 1 I suppose

Comment: Actually this would return any value where the first number is 1. 100, 1000, 13209587203957, etc

Comment: Ah, he edited the question. You're right, the original question asked for that. Apparently he now wants any numbers in front of words? "211 pies"?

Answer (score 0):

A simple one without regular expressions:

```
SELECT *, SUBSTR(my_field, 1, 1) AS mf FROM my_table HAVING mf BETWEEN '0' AND '9';
```

The quotes in the between clause are important!